# ASP / XML Parsing with Proxy

Tags: xml, asp-classic, proxy

I need the add a proxy for the request below.  Please let me know if anyone knows the best way to added it this code without redoing it too much.  Thanks

```
    TheFeed = "http://www.google.com/newsfeed.xml"
    objXML = Server.CreateObject ("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0") 
    objXML.Async = False
    objXML.SetProperty ("ServerHTTPRequest", True)
    objXML.setRequestHeader ("User-Agent", "asp httprequest") 
    objXML.ResolveExternals = True
    objXML.ValidateOnParse = True
    objXML.Load(TheFeed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TheFeed = "http://www.google.com/newsfeed.xml"
objXML = Server.CreateObject ("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0") 
objXML.Async = False
objXML.SetProperty ("ServerHTTPRequest", True)
objXML.setRequestHeader ("User-Agent", "asp httprequest") 
objXML.ResolveExternals = True
objXML.ValidateOnParse = True
objXML.setProxy 2, "http=myProxyServer:80", ""
objXML.Load(TheFeed)
```